# Saving json to rails active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I save a plotly chart which is in json
Format to rails database and then retrieve to
Use and execute in online practice SAT math tests? I want to create these practice tests dynamically based on student performance.

Comment: What have you researched and tried so far? Where are you specifically having trouble in implementing what it is you want to achieve?

Comment: You could store the json object as a serialized attribute: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods.html

Or, if you could store it in a JSONB column: https://tirdadc.github.io/blog/2016/11/03/practical-use-of-jsonb-attributes-in-ruby-on-rails-forms/

Answer (score 1):

```
class ModelName < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :field_name, JSON
end
```

Do like this in your model

Also define your field as `string`

Comment: Thanks. When I retrieve the chart from the database and want to display in view will I have to use eval() to execute the javascript

Comment: The idea is that I will retrieve problems for each student based on past performance. Problems have very specific JavaScript for charts, graphs and randomize get multiple choice answers... all this code needs to be saved as data ... so far using eval() to execute the retrieved long string of code hasn't worked.