# Need save json to rails active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I save a plotly chart which is in json Format to rails database and then retrieve to Use and execute in online practice SAT math tests? I want to create these practice tests dynamically based on student performance.

Comment: hmmm https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45580236/saving-json-to-rails-active-record

Answer (score 0):

Rails with Postgresql supports `json` and `jsonb` datatypes.

```
# ... for json datatype:
create_table :events do |t|
  t.json 'payload'
end
# ... or for jsonb datatype:
create_table :events do |t|
  t.jsonb 'payload'
end

# app/models/event.rb
  class Event < ApplicationRecord
end

# Usage
Event.create(payload: { kind: "user_renamed", change: ["jack", "john"]})

event = Event.first
event.payload # => {"kind"=>"user_renamed", "change"=>["jack", "john"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `serialize` method to serialize any kind of object irrespective of the database.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods.html